Use a LWC Button on the Hightlight Panel without using Dynamic Actions because other forms needs to have the old standard
I've created an apex class to identify in which Status a Case is and if It's on "B" It changes the Status to "A" and the users need to choose when this is going to happen, It means clicking on a button, so I've tried to use the quick action button (using LWC) but It's not visible on the record page, also I've tried to use VisualForce Page and It worked, but It opens another tab instead of just doing the action I want. I've also tried using the Aura component to call the LWC but It opens a modal with the button created on the LWC. On a last try, I've created an Autolaunched Flow to call It using Buttons but also opens a new tab and does the action,
I need to create It on the Highlight Panel without using Dynamic Actions because other forms need to have the old standard and It changes for all,
What can I do to solve It?
Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
André Rödel.
